# disable/hide drop down options(fetched from database) selected in previous drop down field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have multiple drop down menus all having same options. In a particular drop down field, I want to **disable or hide** the values which have been selected in previous drop down field. 

**Eg:
If we have 3 options (A,B,C) and we select A in drop down 1, then A should be hidden or disabled in the remaining drop downs and any dynamic changes should be reflected accordingly.**

The drop down values are being fetched from the database and displayed in the list.

Following is the html code.

```
<select class="form-control" th:name="course1" th:id="course1">
    <option th:value="Preference_1" style="color:#8F8B87" selected>Select Preference 1</option>
    <option th:each="i : ${courseList}" th:value="${i.electiveCourseId}" th:text="${i.electiveName}" style="color:#000"></option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" th:name="course2" th:id="course2">
    <option th:value="Preference_2" style="color:#8F8B87" selected>Select Preference 2</option>
    <option th:each="i : ${courseList}" th:value="${i.electiveCourseId}" th:text="${i.electiveName}" style="color:#000"></option>
</select>
```

**Looking for a jQuery solution for the mentioned problem.**

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a change handler for each field. https://api.jquery.com/change

Then in the function, grab the value that was selected. Finally, find that option in the other dropdowns and give it the "disabled" attribute.